# Is it ok to use a Haswell CPU with old power supply?

Tags: cpu, power-supply, computer-building

I will buy a [i7 4790k](http://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz), and I want to know if I might encountered any problem using it with a old 250W power supply.

I'm planing to get a new power supply also, but only when a I got my video card. But I'll have to wait a couple of months as I don't have enough money to get all three at the same time, and having the processor earlier would be great.

I know that the power efficiency of the power supply I have is extremely bad (around 70%), but according to what I read so far in other forums like Tom's Hardware, some people say it is ok if I disable `C-State` (which I don't know if it's good).

This awful build will be running for no more than 4 months, my biggest concern is if that may damage the CPU in any way.

Comment: Why would it damage your hardware?  If your power supply doesn't support a power state, your CPU will fail to enter that state, resulting you disabling any attempts to do so.

Comment: I have a review of this power supply (but it is other language), saying that the noise level of it is above expected.

Comment: I assume your using it currently, and is not causing a problem, if you are concerned handle the power supply issue now.

Comment: Also, if you're getting a new PSU, always opt for one that has more Wattage than you need, that way if you upgrade parts, you won't always have to upgrade your PSU

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt worry about C-States too much , Its a power saving feature . 
The old PSU might not be stable at lower levels wich means you might need to turn your PSU on and off a lot ,but  you can turn this off in the BIOS, it wont cause any damage.